# How can I align the BPM/Tempo with this audio track using Logic Pro X, Cubase or Ableton?

Tags: tempo, daw, logic-pro, audio-editing

I have downloaded a November Rain orchestral track on which I would like to add a click using one of the DAWs: Logic Pro X, Cubase Elements or Ableton. Below the link with the track (one is the orchestral one while the other is the same instrumental track, but with guitars, drums, etc... I would only need the orchestral one without guitars, drums, etc...):

[November Rain](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1u8hUVzh2rko82zpb-0AsgT96V2lW8WRF)

I would like to use the orchestral track with the click in order to practice on the piano.

I tried to use Smart Tempo on Logic Pro X, trying with KEEP and ADAPT modes, I also edited the project preferences and set the "Set imported audio files to" option to "On + Align Bars and Beats".
However, I couldn't obtain a satisfiable result and the resulting track is out of time with the metronome. Using the File Tempo Editor seems really tricky because the string parts don't have sharp transients and I cannot see them on the audio track in order to align the beats.

What else could I do? I have the Cubase or Ableton option at hand, too, but with them I do know how I can achieve this. If someone could advise me something it would be great!

Thank you for the attention.

Comment: You could manually make a click track and then practice against it.

Comment: Yes, but it would be funnier with the backing track and maybe after I will record myself with the backing track in the background, that's why I would need it to be aligned with the tempo, do you have any advice on how I can do it?

Comment: I meant you would manually make the click track aligned with the backing track. Hit record on a midi track while playing the backing track, and play in the clicks. Edit as desired afterwards.

Comment: That's a good idea! I didn't think about it. Will try it, thank you!

Comment: If the strings track is in sync with the original full band mix, you could load both into your DAW, sync them, and then have the rhythm of the full mix analyzed.

Comment: @YourUncleBob Yes, they are in sync, I tried what you suggest but the problem is that the DAW has troubles to sync the tempo even on the full mix track... Maybe I am doing something wrong? I tried to use Logic's Smart Tempo like I wrote in the question

Answer (score 1):

Even though both the audios have different relative starting points

[image]

both are in sync (OP's comment) hence the tempo will also be same for both so finding the tempo of the audio with guitars, drums will do the trick.

This can be done in Logic Pro X using the **[BPM Counter](https://help.apple.com/logicpro/mac/10.4.7/index.html?localePath=en.lproj#/lgcef24f3fd9)** plugin on the track with drums.

[image]

A few things to keep in mind -

> - LPX's BPM Counter plugin works best on tracks with more obvious transients.
> - Best practice is to play the whole track with the plugin enabled but if you are short of time, you can set the playhead to the point where drums are starting.

In this particular case, it is at 1:38

[image: Time Display Logic Pro]

Once you start the playback, the BPM Counter will start blinking, which means it is analysing it.

[image]

Let this continue for some  time and you'll see numbers will start to blink on the plugin screen

[image]

After a while, it will settle on one number - That's the BPM.

The BPM of the track in question is 78ish (BPM Counter reading is 77.9) but 78 should work for Piano practice.

More on BPM Counter [here](https://help.apple.com/logicpro/mac/10.4.7/index.html?localePath=en.lproj#/lgcef24f3fd9).

---